# Lower mp4 file size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have couple of (over 100) mp4 video files, which are approximately 15 MB each. I think they are unnecessarily high quality videos, I want to lower the sizes of each, by reducing the quality. I know I can do this with ffmpeg, but I am not familiar with concepts like bitrates, codes etc, so can anyone help with that? This is metadata of one of them:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '16.8-AnomalyDetection-AnomalyDetectionUsingTheMultivariateGaussianDistribution-OPTIONAL.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2011-12-06 18:56:20
  Duration: 00:14:03.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1000x562 [SAR 1:1 DAR 500:281], 45 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-12-06 18:56:20
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
```

Comment: You do realize that the *audio* is responsible for over 70% of your file size?

Comment: No I do not :) As I say, I am not particularly good with audio and video encodings.

Comment: You can see the lines that contain `Audio` and `Video`, with the former having `127 kb/s` and the latter `45 kb/s`, making up almost all of the total `176 kb/s`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in $(find .. -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mp4'); do 
    filename=$(echo "$d" | sed 's:../::')
    ffmpeg -i "$d" -b:a 64k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -acodec libmp3lame -s\
    640x480 -r 10 "$filename" && rm --interactive=never "$d"
done
```

**Options stands for:**

- *-b:a* -> Set audio bitrate
- *-ac* ->   Set the number of audio channels.
- *-ar* ->   Set the audio sampling frequency
- *-s* ->  Set video dimensions.
- *-r* ->    Set frames per second